# Can anyone identify this Yukon solitaire variant?

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

So since I was a kid my grandma has always been playing the same kind of solitaire. But no one knows the name. After some digging I found out it must be some form of Yukon.

Deck:
Standard 52 card deck with no jokers.

Deal:
7 rows, first card face up, then 6 cards face down, repeat til the base is filled face up.
Then deal the rest of the cards on the six rows (face up) and let the first row stand alone with one card. (face up)

Play:
Same way as standard yukon, except you can only put the same type on each other in decending order: five of spades on six of spades etc.

Goal:
Build 4 foundations with ace at the foundation and building upwards from there in the same suit and type.

I play this all the time and would love to know the name!